# Is there a way to search next in tmux

Tags: tmux

I understand to search is to use c^b / , but it only work once. Is there a way to keep searching for the next without typing the searching keyword every time?

Answer (score 4):

It looks you refer to searching in a copy mode, entered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>,<kbd>[</kbd> by default. Then <kbd>/</kbd> indeed initializes searching forward in vi mode (and it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> in emacs mode).

> Is there a way to keep searching for the next without typing the searching keyword every time?

Yes. After the first search hit <kbd>n</kbd>. To search in reverse use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>. These default bindings are the same in vi and emacs mode.

This is the relevant fragment from [man 1 tmux](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux):

> A tmux window may be in one of several modes. The default permits direct access to the terminal attached to the window. The other is copy mode, which permits a section of a window or its history to be copied to a paste buffer for later insertion into another window. This mode is entered with the `copy-mode` command, bound to <kbd>[</kbd> by default. It is also entered when a command that produces output, such as `list-keys`, is executed from a key binding.
>
> The keys available depend on whether emacs or vi mode is selected (see the `mode-keys` option). The following keys are supported as appropriate for the mode:
>
> ```
> Function                  vi  emacs
> [...]
> Search again              n   n
> Search again in reverse   N   N
> Search backward           ?   C-r
> Search forward            /   C-s
> ```

Comment: It's probably worth to mention that "the first search" might mean pressing enter with the query being written in the search prompt.